# GAPI & GIS migration - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'client')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api-js-client

**Issue :**
Want to provide google sign-in using GSI API. And access Gmail API (gapi) using gsi as do not want to rewrite complete Gmail API logic.

**Q1.** How to access gapi variable from gapi library as its included in index.html and need to be accessed in a component?
**Q2.** Why does it always complain that gapi is undefined even though I have loaded and tried to call the required method as per Google migrating docs ( refer here: https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#gapi-asyncawait)?

index.html:

```html
<bdoy>
....
....
 <script
      async
      defer
      src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"

    ></script>
    <script
      async
      defer
      src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client"

    ></script>
</body>
```

component:

```js
class GoogleLogin extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    window.gapiLoadOkay();
    window.gisLoadOkay();
    const gsiGApiPromise= async () => await handleGSIGAPILoad();
  }

  setSignedInStatus(loginStatus) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state, isSignedInUser: loginStatus
    })
  }
  signOutFromGoogle(e) {
    handleSignoutClick(e).then(() => {
      // console.log('isSignedIn():', isSignedIn())
      // this.setSignedInStatus(isSignedIn());
      console.log('isSignedInUser2:', this.state.isSignedInUser);
    });
  }
  syncMyData(e) {
    rescanMessages(getBasicProfile().getEmail());
  }
  signInWithGoogle(e) {
    console.log('isSignedInUser:', this.state.isSignedInUser);
    handleAuthClick(e).then((e2) => {
      showProfile();
      console.log('isSignedInUser2:', this.state.isSignedInUser);
    });

  }
  componentDidMount(){
    window.gapiLoadOkay();
    window.gisLoadOkay();
    const gsiGApiPromise= async () => await handleGSIGAPILoad();
    showProfile();
    
  }
  render() {
    // console.log('isSignedIn()2:', isSignedIn());
    return (
      <div>
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>
            <div className='row'>
              <div className='col-2'>

                <div id="g_id_onload"
                  data-client_id="CLIENT_ID"
                  data-context="signin"
                  data-ux_mode="popup"
                  data-callback="signInToGoogle"
                  data-nonce=""
                  data-auto_select="true">
                </div>

                <div className="g_id_signin"
                  onClick={(e) => this.signInWithGoogle(e)}
                  data-type="icon"
                  data-shape="circle"
                  data-theme="outline"
                  data-text="signin_with"
                  data-size="large">
                </div>
                
              </div>

            </div>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleLogin;
```

service script:

```js
/* Magrating to GIS with GAPI 
// refer to https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis
*/

export const gapiLoadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  window.gapiLoadOkay = resolve;
  window.gapiLoadFail = reject;
});
const gisLoadPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  window.gisLoadOkay = resolve;
  window.gisLoadFail = reject;
});

var tokenClient;

export const handleGSIGAPILoad = async () => {
  // document.getElementById("showEventsBtn").style.visibility="hidden";
  // document.getElementById("revokeBtn").style.visibility="hidden";
console.log('await gapiLoadPromise ')
  // First, load and initialize the gapi.client
  await gapiLoadPromise;
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // NOTE: the 'auth2' module is no longer loaded.
    console.log('await gapiLoadPromise 2')
    gapi.load('client', { callback: resolve, onerror: reject });
  });
  await gapi.client.init({
    // NOTE: OAuth2 'scope' and 'client_id' parameters have moved to initTokenClient().
  })
    .then(function () {  // Load the Calendar API discovery document.
      console.log('gapi client is loading 3');
      gapi.client.load(DISCOVERY_DOCS);
    });

  // Now load the GIS client
  await gisLoadPromise;
  await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        prompt: 'consent',
        callback: callbackFunctionForGis,  // defined at request time in await/promise scope.
      });
      console.log('gis client is loading');
      resolve();
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });

  // document.getElementById("showEventsBtn").style.visibility="visible";
  // document.getElementById("revokeBtn").style.visibility="visible";
};
// handleGSIGAPILoad();
async function getToken(err) {

  if (err.result.error.code == 401 || (err.result.error.code == 403) &&
    (err.result.error.status == "PERMISSION_DENIED")) {

    // The access token is missing, invalid, or expired, prompt for user consent to obtain one.
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        // Settle this promise in the response callback for requestAccessToken()
        tokenClient.callback = (resp) => {
          if (resp.error !== undefined) {
            reject(resp);
          }
          // GIS has automatically updated gapi.client with the newly issued access token.
          console.log('gapi.client access token: ' + JSON.stringify(gapi.client.getToken()));
          resolve(resp);
        };
        tokenClient.requestAccessToken();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
    });
  } else {
    // Errors unrelated to authorization: server errors, exceeding quota, bad requests, and so on.
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}

export function showProfile() {

  // Try to fetch a list of Calendar events. If a valid access token is needed,
  // prompt to obtain one and then retry the original request.
  gapi.client.gmail.users.getProfile({
    userId: "me",
  })
    .then(profileResponse => console.log(JSON.stringify(profileResponse)))
    .catch(err => getToken(err))  // for authorization errors obtain an access token
    .then(retry => gapi.client.gmail.users.getProfile({
      userId: "me",
    }))
    .then(profileResponse => console.log(JSON.stringify(profileResponse)))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));   // cancelled by user, timeout, etc.
}

function revokeToken() {
  let cred = gapi.client.getToken();
  if (cred !== null) {
    google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(cred.access_token, () => { console.log('Revoked: ' + cred.access_token) });
    gapi.client.setToken('');
  }
}

function callbackFunctionForGis(){
  console.log('Hi this is a sample callback 123')
}
```